# Catch derived class Exceptions in base class with different methods and arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make something like base "exception handler" thing. So this base class will try-catch exceptions **when any method (with any number of parameters) in derived class gets invoked**. I'm not good in describing this with words, so here is the scenario:

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
    Exception _ex;

    public Exception LastKnownException
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ex;
        }
    }

    //...
    //what do I do here to assign the value of above property when some random exception occur in derived class?
    //...

    //The closest I can get...
    public void RunMethod(Action method)
    {
        try
        {
            method.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._ex = ex;
        }
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{   
    public void DoRandomMethod(int couldBeOfAnyTypeHere, bool andIndefiniteNumberOfThese)
    {
        bool result = false;
        var someObject = new OtherClass(couldBeOfAnyTypeHere, out andIndefiniteNumberOfThese);

        someObject.DoInternalWork(result); // <-- here is where I need the base class to take care if any exception should occur
    }

    public int AnotherMethod(int? id)
    {       
        if (!id.HasValue) 
            id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["client_id"]);

        var someOtherObject = new OtherClassB(id.Value);

        return someOtherObject.CheckSomething(); // <-- and catch possible exceptions for this one too
    }

    //The closest I can get... (see base class implementation)
    public List<RandomClass> GetSomeListBy(int id)
    {
        RunMethod(() => 
            string[] whateverArgs = new[] { "is", "this", "even", "possible?" };

            YetAnotherStaticClass.GetInstance().ExecuteErrorProneMethod(whateverArgs); // <-- Then when something breaks here, the LastKnownException will have something
        );
    }
}

public class TransactionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ShowSomething()
    {
        var dc = new DerivedClass();

        dc.DoRandomMethod(30, true);

        if (dc.LastKnownException != null)
        {
            //optionally do something here
            return RedirectToAction("BadRequest", "Error", new { ex = dc.LastKnownException });
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }       
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: My simple approach will work, only, I don't want to have to wrap all methods with this lambda-driven `RunMethod()` method all the time -- I need the base class to somehow intercept any incoming exception and return the `Exception` object to the derived class without throwing the error.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. And thanks in advance!

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using the event [System.AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

This event will be raised whenever an exception occurs that is not handled.

As you don't clutter your code with the possibilities of exception, your code will be much better readable. Besides it would give derived classes the opportunity to catch exceptions if they expect ones, without interfering with your automatic exception catcher.

Your design is such, that if someone calls several functions of your derived class and then checks if there are any exceptions the caller wouldn't know which function caused the exception. I assume that your caller is not really interested in which function causes the exception. This is usually the case if you only want to log exception until someone investigates them.

If that is the case consider doing something like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    if (ex != null)
        logger.LogException(ex);
    // TODO: decide whether to continue or exit.
}
```

If you really want to do this only for your abstract base class

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
    private List<Exception> unhandledExceptions = new List<Exception>();

    protected BaseClass()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;
    }

private void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    if (ex != null)
        this.UnhandledExceptions.Add(ex);
}

public List<Exception> LastKnownExceptions
{
    get { return this.unhandledExceptions; }
}
```

Comment: This `AppDomain.UnhandledException` is new to me and I will definitely look into it! Thanks! But in case of your "the called wouldn't know which function caused the exception", maybe I will use some custom class to hold more info for this exception.

Comment: I have one question though: When this `BaseClass` is derived by multiple classes, since it's initialized in the constructor, will the global event handler always reset? Or be replaced?

Comment: You didn't write what you want with the exceptions. Because you had no mechanism to detect which of the calls caused the exception, nor a method to handle several exceptions I assumed you didn't want to do a lot with it, maybe logging, Apparently you really do want to do something with the exceptions. Are you sure their occurrence is exceptional? If not: consider return value. If exceptional, is the exception a property of the whole class, or does the exception belong to the function you called? If it belongs to the function, why design it as part of the class?

Comment: Okay, so the `Exception` occurence would be optional and I'm planning to use this to check if the exception is of certain type (custom `Exception` class) and do something with it, like setting the server `Response.StatusCode` to something for even further processing in the client side, like showing certain message accordingly. For such case, what would I best do then? Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement for catching exceptions, but used a specific implementation (i.e. not an abstract class) to encapsulate the handling of errors.

Please note this takes in an argument for any expected exceptions (params Type[] catchableExceptionTypes), but of course you can modify to suit your own requirements.

```
public class ExceptionHandler
{
    // exposes the last caught exception
    public Exception CaughtException { get; private set; }

    // allows a quick check to see if an exception was caught
    // e.g. if (ExceptionHandler.HasCaughtException) {... do something...}
    public bool HasCaughtException { get; private set; }

    // perform an action and catch any expected exceptions
    public void TryAction(Action action, params Type[] catchableExceptionTypes)
    {
        Reset();
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (ExceptionIsCatchable(exception, catchableExceptionTypes))
            {
                return;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    // perform a function and catch any expected exceptions
    // if an exception is caught, this returns null
    public T TryFunction<T>(Func<T> function,  params Type[] catchableExceptionTypes) where T : class
    {
        Reset();
        try
        {
            return function();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (ExceptionIsCatchable(exception, catchableExceptionTypes))
            {
                return null;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    bool ExceptionIsCatchable(Exception caughtException, params Type[] catchableExceptionTypes)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < catchableExceptionTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            var catchableExceptionType = catchableExceptionTypes[i];
            if (!IsAssignableFrom(caughtException, catchableExceptionType)) continue;
            CaughtException = caughtException;
            HasCaughtException = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static bool IsAssignableFrom(Exception exception, Type type)
    {
        if (exception.GetType() == type) return true;
        var baseType = exception.GetType().BaseType;
        while (baseType != null)
        {
            if (baseType == type) return true;
            baseType = baseType.BaseType;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        CaughtException = null;
        HasCaughtException = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! But in case you missed my last edit, "I don't want to have to wrap all methods with this lambda-driven method all the time -- I need the base class to somehow intercept any incoming exception and return the Exception object to the derived class without throwing the error."